# Couchbase - deserialize json into dynamic type

Tags: json, deserialization, couchbase

I'm trying to deserialize some JSON coming back from couchbase into a dynamic type.
The document is something like this so creating a POCO for this would be overkill:

```
{
    UsersOnline: 1
}
```

I figured that something like this would do the trick, but it seems to deserialize into a dynamic object with the value just being the original JSON

```
var jsonObj = _client.GetJson<dynamic>(storageKey);
```

results in:

```
jsonObj { "online": 0 }
```

Is there anyway I can get the couchbase deserializer to generate the dynamic type for me?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default deserializer for the client uses .NET's binary serializer, so when you save or read a JSON string, it's just a string.  GetJson will always just return a string.  However, there are a couple of options:

You could convert JSON records to Dictionary instances:

```
var appJson = "{ \"UsersOnline\" : 1, \"NewestMember\" : \"zblock\" }";
var result = client.ExecuteStore(StoreMode.Set, "userCount", appJson);
var item = client.GetJson<Dictionary<string, object>>("userCount");
Console.WriteLine("There are {0} users online.  The newest member is {1}.",
                    item["UsersOnline"], item["NewestMember"]);
```

Or you could use a dynamic ExpandoObject instance:

```
var appJson = "{ \"UsersOnline\" : 1, \"NewestMember\" : \"zblock\" }";
var result = client.ExecuteStore(StoreMode.Set, "userCount", appJson);
dynamic item = client.GetJson<ExpandoObject>("userCount");
Console.WriteLine("There are {0} users online.  The newest member is {1}.",
                    item.UsersOnline, item.NewestMember);
```

In either case you're losing static type checking, which seems like it's OK for your purposes.  In both cases you get access to the JSON properties without having to parse the JSON into a POCO though...

Edit: I wrote a couple of extension methods that may be useful and blogged about them at http://blog.couchbase.com/moving-no-schema-stack-c-and-dynamic-types

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the answer - where is the item variable coming from in the above examples? Also how are the records being converted to dictionaries? It's morning so I might just need my coffee before I can understand this, cheers

Comment: Oops!  I forgot to copy & paste the most important lines - the actual Get.  Sorry about that.  I've updated the code to include the item assignment.

Comment: ExpandoObject was exactly what I was looking for - Ended up creating a 5 line POCO in the .cs file, but these are some good alternatives, cheers!

Comment: Glad that worked for you - and I finally found a good use case for ExpandoObject.  :)

Comment: Wow just saw your blogpost and extension methods - awesome :-)